# how to grab email  from the place holder using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

How do I grab the value from the below code in selenium webdriver using java

```
<script id="metamorph-0-start" type="text/x-placeholder"/>
test@gmail.com
<script id="metamorph-0-end" type="text/x-placeholder"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be tempted to answer:

```
String email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('metamorph-0-start')/..')")).getText();
```

But that will only work if there are no other text siblings/descendants.

I'm going to assume a few things, one is that your html actually is:

```
<script id="metamorph-0-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
test@gmail.com
<script id="metamorph-0-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
```

To really just get the email I would do this using Javascript:

```
String email = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
    "return arguments[0].nextSibling.textContent.split('\\n')[1]",
    driver.findElement(By.id("metamorph-0-start")));
```

You could also do the newline stripping in Java instead of in Javascript.

Comment: That first expression seems strange to me. Is it valid XPath 1.0? I'd expect `//*[@id='metamorph-0-start']/..`

Comment: @Slanec Holy crap, it is! http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-id How could I live without it?

Answer (score 0):

Without more knowledge about the page (or the containing element), I think TunaBum has the best answer.

That said, based on the assumption that that's the only e-mail address (or rather text with an at-sign in int) on the page, you could do

```
String email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'@')]")).getText();
```

that gets text of an element which contains an `@` in its text.

If your containing element has multiple `metamorph-number-start/end` in it, and every one of them contain some text, then JS is your only path since `WebDriver` can't yet work with text nodes.